# Cannot Resolve Local Dependencies with Maven

Tags: maven

I am trying to add dependencies to meet the parent project defined in a project I'm working on. I have tried both just copying the dependencies to the same folder as the rest of my local repository, as auto-populated by Maven; and writing a user setting XML defines a local repository where the files I need to add are stored. But I am getting the following error.

settings.xml

```
<settings>
        <localRepository>[path to dependencies]</localRepository>
    <offline>true</offline>
</settings>
```

Error:

> Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find
>   com.vmware.rabbitmq:rabbitmq-training-parent:pom:1.0.0 in
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and
>   'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 10 ->
>   [Help 2]

How can I manually add files to my local maven repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [guide](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) on Maven website how to do that. You need to run following command

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> 
-DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

Comment: I misunderstood those directions when searching for my answer. Thanks for giving me the link, and quoting the instructions.